# Probability, picking balls from urn

Tags: probability

From urn where are $30$ white balls and $20$ black balls we randomly pick one without returning. How to calculate the probability where we pick white ball in fourth time.

I tried to draw a tree and denote the branches by relevant probability but I get a weird outcome here's my [attempt](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F5%2829%2F49%2828%2F48%2827%2F47%29%2B20%2F18%2828%2F47%29%29%2B20%2F49%2829%2F48%2828%2F47%29%2B19%2F48%2829%2F47%29%29%29%2B2%2F5%2830%2F49%2819%2F48%2829%2F47%29%2B29%2F48%2828%2F47%29%29%2B19%2F49%2830%2F48%2829%2F47%29%2B18%2F48%2830%2F47%29%29)

@EDIT after amendment [attempt](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F5%2829%2F49%2828%2F48%2827%2F47%29%2B20%2F48%2828%2F47%29%29%2B20%2F49%2829%2F48%2828%2F47%29%2B19%2F48%2829%2F47%29%29%29%2B2%2F5%2830%2F49%2819%2F48%2829%2F47%29%2B29%2F48%2828%2F47%29%29%2B19%2F49%2830%2F48%2829%2F47%29%2B18%2F48%2830%2F47%29%29)

Comment: Without calculation, the answer (for the $4$-th ball, or the $17$-th) is $30/50$.

Comment: could you clarify why is that?

Comment: Suppose the balls are all distinct (give them student numbers). Imagine drawing them all out, one at a time. All orders of drawing are equally likely. So the probability a certain ball is $17$-th is $\frac{1}{50}$. There are $30$ red, so the probability the $17$-th is red is $\frac{30}{50}$. First, fourth, seventeenth, it doesn't matter.

Comment: It is not a bad idea, however, to do it the "hard" way, like you did. Makes one appreciate the easy way!

Comment: Thank you, great solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that a tree is a nice graphical approach.  Fortunately, there are "only" $2^3 = 8$ branches you need to consider after the third pick.  For any of those eight branches, you can determine the probability that you reached that branch, as well as the probability of picking a W ball from that branch.

For example, if you are on the first branch, lets say you got there by drawing three white balls in a row with probability $\frac{30}{50} \frac{29}{49} \frac{28}{48}$.  Then the probability of drawing white again is $\frac{27}{47}$.  That is for that single branch, but you can easily compute the other 7 branches.

Once you have each branch probability $P_{b}$, and the probability of choosing white from that branch $P_{bW}$, you can determine the total probability of choosing white.

Comment: ohh I made a stupid mistake during typing my calculation to wolfram in one moment i wrote 18 instead of 48 and it changed my outcome to $0.6$ which is correct answer but thanks for engagement

Comment: Oh no, thank you for choosing my answer ;)